# The Lagrangian and energy density.

Tags: physics, calculus-of-variations, classical-mechanics

Can we understand the founding principle of **Lagrangian mechanics** in the following way?

If a mass particle follows the path $x(t)$, then we have the two types of energy: kinetic energy $T(x(t))$ and potential energy $V(x(t))$. The usual total energy is the sum $E=T+V$.

For every $t'\in \mathbb{R}$ we can define a scalar field $U(x(t')) = \sqrt{ T^2(x(t'))+V^2(x(t'))}$ that represents the *generalized energy magnitude* of the conjugate energies $T$ and $V$. Because the Nature favors uniformity, we wish to minimize the curvature $U$ over the time period $[t_i,t_f]$ when the particle moves from $x(t_i)$ to $x(t_f)$. We can simplify the problem by noting that $U=\sqrt{T^2+(E-T)^2}$ and treat $T$ as an independent variable. Thus, by taking the derivative, we have the minimum at $T=E/2$. Hence, we have $V=E-T = E/2=T$. Thus, if we wish to minimize $U$, then we must minimize the difference $|T-V|$. The remaining question is to find the path $x_*(t)$ that minimizes the following integral

$$\int_{t_i}^{t_f}(T-V)dt.$$

Comment: What is the energy density of a point particle, why is it $U$? Please, can you provide any reference for your definition of $U$? Which is the relation with entropy? Again, which is the meaning of "entropy of a system composed by a single point particle"?

Comment: @mrcntn Well, I consider the density in the set of all the possible paths, and $T$ and $V$ are fields that store energy. No references, this is just speculative handwaving :)

Comment: This seems interesting, could you please elaborate or provide a reference for this construction of $U$?

Comment: @mrcntn It's an analogy of "energy density of electric and magnetic fields".

Comment: Sorry but Physics is not based on analogies (they can be useful, but only when meaningful). You should rethink which is the real meaning of $U$ on some mathematical and physical basis. Just my advice :)

Comment: @mrcntn Now you have the definiton, I pulled it out of a top hat :)

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a good justification for the use of the quantity $T-V$ as the Lagrangian.  A more qualitative way I’d phrase it as well is to say that the optimal path a particle follows is the one where the kinetic energy is driven solely by the potential energy constraints imposed on the system.  Therefore, to guarantee that the kinetic energy matches the potential we would like $T\approx V$, or equivalently $T-V$ to be minimized.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!